# Turn off eslint warning: Newline required at end of file but not found. (eol-last)

Tags: html, reactjs, jsx, eslint

How do I stop eslint from warning about missing newlines at the end of files?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I fixed it by doing

```
 "eol-last": 0,
 "no-multiple-empty-lines": ["error", { "max": 1, "maxEOF": 0 }],
```

eol-last seems to take enums now so 0 is never and im not sure what 1 and 2 do as they are the other values it allowed me to put in without erroring,

Answer (score 2):

Add this in your eslint config :

```
eol-last: ["error", "never"]
```

"never" enforces that files do not end with a newline

Another option: 
try doing this by using the rule "no-multiple-empty-lines".

```
"no-multiple-empty-lines": [2, {"max": 99999, "maxEOF": 0}]
```

max sets the maximum number of consecutive blank lines.

maxEOF can be used to set a different number for the end of file. The last blank lines will then be treated differently. If omitted, the max option is applied everywhere.
Assuming you don't care about the number of empty lines between code, just set max to a high number.

Comment: it says that it wants never to be an enum

Comment: try doing this by using the rule no-multiple-empty-lines.

"no-multiple-empty-lines": [2, {"max": 99999, "maxEOF": 0}]
max sets the maximum number of consecutive blank lines.

maxEOF can be used to set a different number for the end of file. The last blank lines will then be treated differently. If omitted, the max option is applied everywhere.
Assuming you don't care about the number of empty lines between code, just set max to a high number. (Updated this in the answer)

Comment: @andy wilson: 
"eol-last": 0 // does not throw any error or simply it ignores if there is/not any new line at the end of file.
"eol-last": 1 // gives you warning if there is NO new line at the end of file.
"eol-last": 2 // gives you error if there is NO new line at the end of file. It basically says it requires a new line at the end of the file.

you do not need "eol-last":0

Comment: I would like to have comments on downvotes. Please explain your reason to downvote the answer. It will help me in improving my answer.

Comment: I didnt downvote i upvoted someone else downvoted it

Comment: He he...yeah I know you didn't. :) I was just trying to reach the person who downvoted the answer and want to know the reason , so that I can improve my answer. Btw thanks for upvoting ...glad it helped you!

Comment: i dont understand why people downvoted my post and its now locked cause its unintelligible according to mods but you knew what i was talking about plus so did the other guy

Comment: yeah true. People should give the reason behind their downvote. Simply downvoting doesn't help. A specific reason would be helpful for both the questioner/answerer to review their question/answer.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest fix is putting this at the beginning of your .ts file

```
/* eslint-disable eol-last */
```

Problem solved :-)

Answer (score 2):

I also get the same error, so I easily solve it simply by adding 2 lines in my `package.json's` scripts

```
"lint": "eslint --ext \".js,.vue\" --ignore-path .gitignore .",

"lint-fix": "npm run lint -- --fix"
```

Comment: npm run lint -- --fix runned in same folder with eslint, fixed my problem.. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Look for `eol-last` in your eslint config and remove it. Or set it to never explicitly like so:

```
eol-last: ["error", "never"]
```

See http://eslint.org/docs/rules/eol-last

Comment: it says never must be an enum value

Comment: I only get that error, when I put a 0 as value: `Value "0" must be an enum value.` Do you use the latest version of eslint?

Answer (score 1):

Adding **one empty line** at the **end** works for me

Answer (score 0):

If you are using visual studio then in the visual studio go at the problem section right click over it and click it on fix the issue.

New Line Problem means one more new line required. Press enter at the end.